# How to render a game every 100th time in Python gym, for reinforcement learning

Tags: python, openai-gym

I have used an example game Frozen lake to train the model to find the reward. I tried to render every 100th time it played the game, but was not able to.
This is my skinned-down version:

```py
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1',render_mode = "human") 

state=env.reset()

for episode in range(EPISODES):
   state=env.reset()
   
   for _ in range(100):
       action = env.action_space.sample() #random action
       next_state, reward, done,info, _ = env.step(action) #takes action
   
         #render the game very 100th time
         if episode % 10 == 0:
                print("ep: ", episode)
                 env.render()
```

Even if I delete the render statement, the game still renders every time.